# How do I use jQuery to add a glyphicon?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a jQuery snippet I want to edit to add a glyphicon (with styling) wrapped in a span into a div, instead of the plain text as shown below. Any advice?

Here's the jQuery:

```
$('#closeOpenDataControlSwitch').html(function() {
    $(this).text("-");
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="closeOpenDataControlSwitch">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger></span>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Instead of adding text with jQuery, I want to add a span that consists of 2 classes. The HTML shows how the span is currently placed, but I want the jQuery to load it instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `append`

```js
$('#closeOpenDataControlSwitch').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger">Added Span</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="closeOpenDataControlSwitch"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!